# Android Vibrate Service (Vibrator) is not working for long time

Tags: android, android-vibration, system-setting

I want to Vibrate a phone for long time(e.g 2 minutes) but It vibrates for very less time.
i am using this code

```
Vibrator mVibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
mVibrate.vibrate(2*60*1000); // 2 Minutes
```

How to vibrate for 2 or 3 minutes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way for long viabration as follows,

```
Vibrator mVibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
long pattern[]={0,800,200,1200,300,2000,400,4000};
// 2nd argument is for repetition pass -1 if you do not want to repeat the Vibrate
mVibrate.vibrate(pattern,-1);
```

You can increase the pattern's array for long time viabration.

Comment: If I pass 10(for repeating 10 times) in place of -1 then vibration does not repeat for 10 times. how to repeat ?

Comment: @AtulBhardwaj which device you are testing ?

Comment: I am using Htc one v (ICS)